# Antialias does not work when applying drop shadow filter in pixi.js

Tags: javascript, antialiasing, pixi.js

I turned on antialias and applied the drop shadow filter to a circle instantiated based on the Graphics class.However, after applying drop shadows, circular antialias does not appear to work. I want to make antialias work while applying drop shadow filters.

[image: two circle]

I am using pixi.js-v5.0.4 and pixi-filters-v3.0.3. I turned on antialias and doubled the resolution. Drop shadow filters and antialias work fine on their own.

Here's the code:

```
app = new PIXI.Application({width: 300, height: 200, antialias: true, resolution: 2, autoResize: true})
document.body.appendChild(app.view)
app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0xffe7b9

function createCircle(x, y) {
  circle = new PIXI.Graphics()
  circle.beginFill(0xFFFFFF)
  circle.lineStyle(3, 0x000000, 1)
  circle.drawCircle(x, y, 60)
  circle.endFill()
  app.stage.addChild(circle)
  return circle
}

circle1 = createCircle(80, 100)
circle2 = createCircle(220, 100)
circle2.filters = [new PIXI.filters.DropShadowFilter()]
```

Comment: "antialiasing works only for main framebuffer. Any filter, renderTexture will ruin it and its webgl problem, not pixi. In WebGL2 its possible to use AA on created framebuffers but pixi-v5 doesnt support that yet." https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/42489-aliasing-when-shadow-filter-is-applied/?do=findComment&comment=240402

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extended answer of [@chris-hayes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2096769/chris-hayes)

> antialiasing works only for main framebuffer. Any filter,
> renderTexture will ruin it and its webgl problem, not pixi. In WebGL2
> its possible to use AA on created framebuffers but pixi-v5 doesnt
> support that yet.
>
> Well, if scale is near 1 you can try adding a transparent frame around
> the card for the texture.
>
> Another approach is to photoshop your shadows into PNG files and use
> extra sprites to show them, and its fastest approach.

From [www.html5gamedevs.com](https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/42489-aliasing-when-shadow-filter-is-applied/?tab=comments#comment-240402)